# bad validation accuracy after restoring the saved model/session although it was good during training-process

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, evaluation, evaluate

I used Tensorflow to implement a LeNet NN and train it on Traffic signs dataset.

After training it I've tried to restore the saved session and evaluate the model on the test-dataset
but I got a very bad accuracy (0.03) although the **training and validation accuracy during training-process were good (0.92 and 0.91)**

I tried to evaluate it on the **validation-dataset** to make sure that I have restored it right
but I got also **very low accuracy (0.02)**

I used this to restore the file

```
logits = LeNet(x, 1)
with tf.Session() as sess:   
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./ckp/lenet_4.ckp.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, "./ckp/lenet_4.ckp")
    
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    accuracy= evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)
    print('valid accuracy = ', accuracy)
```

also used this and got the same problem

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
logits = LeNet(x, 1)
with tf.Session() as sess:   
    saver.restore(sess, "./ckp/lenet_4.ckp")

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 
    accuracy= evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    print('test accuracy = ', accuracy)
```

What might be wrong?
I'll appreciate any ideas/solutions. Thanks

Comment: My initial comment: *"Your model is not generalizing properly. Did you overtrain? Have you used regularization methods?"*. However, upon reading the question more carefully, it sounds like your validation accuracy should be (supposedly) high, but you are not sure how to measure it. Is that the question?

Comment: actually I found my failure.  I shouldn't use sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())